# How to do a transpose a dataframe group by key on pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analytics

I have this table from my database and I need a transpose group by survey_id

```
id  answer  survey_id   question_number questionid 
216     0.0         69               3         2.0   
217     3.0         69               4         3.0   
218     0.0         69               5         4.0   
219     0.0         69               6         5.0   
221     0.0         69               8         7.0
```

Like this:

```
Survey P01  P02 P03 P04 P05
69     1    1   2   2   1
```

The cell is the answer and the column is format "P{question_number}"

I'm using pandas 0.18.1.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you need `print (df.pivot(index='survey_id', columns='question_number', values='answer').add_prefix('P'))` ?

Comment: Thanks! Almost there.. But how can I add a Survey_id as the first column? I tried to stack, but is not exactly I need. The big deal it's use survey_id to merge with another table.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.pivot(index='survey_id', columns='question_number', values='answer')
         .add_prefix('P')
         .reset_index())

question_number  survey_id   P3   P4   P5   P6   P8
0                       69  0.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```