# Get beginning end end date from one column to two columns for each seperate ID

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I've following df

```
ID      Status        Date
1       A             01-09-2020
1       B             03-09-2020
2       A             10-12-2020
2       B             -
```

And would like to convert to this:

```
ID     Status1     Status2      Date1       Date2
1      A           B            01-09-2020  03-09-2020
2      A           B            10-12-2020   -
```

I've think pivot doesn't apply here since I'm not really aggregating something and I've managed somewhat by using a group_by function where I get the min and max date for each ID, and afterwards joining it, but that seems somehow very devious and doesn't give me the status columns for which I cant use the min or max function since this is a numeric value.

I've tried following solution (answer 10 as someone suggested) [How to pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe), which would look like this

```
df.insert(0, 'count', df.groupby('ID').cumcount())
pivot = df.pivot(index='count', columns='ID', values='STATUS')
```

but this resulted in following df:

```
1      2    
A      A
B      B
```

I've also tried [How to do a transpose a dataframe group by key on pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107512/how-to-do-a-transpose-a-dataframe-group-by-key-on-pandas) but this gives me the error

```
Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Also if I use pd.pivot_table() instead of df.pivot as someone else suggested in another post.

Comment: In the output df, ID would be 1, 2. Right?

Comment: Yeah sorry. Will edit it, my mistake

Comment: Question/Answer 10 in the dup link. Your one column is ID.

Comment: @QuangHoang Doesn't work. If I do this I get the IDs as columns and doesn't solve my problem with the status

Comment: Then you should edit your question with that information. I will re-open the question since it shows you tried to solve the problem and failed.

Comment: @QuangHoang, sorry but did you reopen it, because it still shows as closed to me.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you must create two aux dataframes before, the first one grouping by ID and getting the first and last Status (if you are going to have A and B everytime you could use a pivot table) and the second one, you should get the first and last date. Something like that:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "ID": [1, 1, 2, 2],
            "Status": ["A", "B", "A", "B"],
            "Date": ["01-09-2020", "03-09-2020", "10-12-2020", "11-12-2020"]
        }
    )
    .assign(Date=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x["Date"])
)
aux1 = df.groupby("ID").agg(Status1=("Status", "first"), Status2=("Status", "last"))
aux2 = df.groupby("ID").agg(Date1=("Date", "min"), Date2=("Date", "max"))
output = pd.merge(aux1, aux2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(output)
```